# What might be the consequences of disabling Garbage Collection in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, garbage-collection, gunicorn

While running my application, I noticed that pods in Kubernetes reset due to insufficient memory. The reason for this behavior was that the memory after a given request was not freed but was still reserved. Additionally, the next request increased the reserved memory. The workaround for this problem was to properly configure gunicorn, that is, turning the `Garbage Collection` off and on between requests. Below is the solution that can be found in the `gunicorn` configuration file.

```
import gc

bind = ":8000"
worker_tmp_dir = "/dev/shm"
workers = 1
timeout = 300


def pre_request(worker, req):
    gc.disable()


def post_request(worker, req):
    gc.enable()
```

What are the side effects of this solution?

Comment: The side effects are that garbage collection wont run while a request is processing.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry and what could be the negative reasons for disabling it?

Comment: The negative reason for disabling it is because the memory after a given request is reserved, forcing pods in Kubernetes to reset due to insufficient memory.